# Where should you enable SSL?

Tags: performance, security, ssl, https

My last couple of projects have involved websites that sell a product/service and require a 'checkout' process in which users put in their credit card information and such. Obviously we got SSL certificates for the security of it plus giving peace of mind to the customers. I am, however, a little clueless as to the subtleties of it, and most importantly as to which parts of the website should 'use' the certificate.

For example, I've been to websites where the moment you hit the homepage you are put in https - mostly banking sites - and then there are websites where you are only put in https when you are finally checking out. Is it overkill to make the entire website run through https if it doesn't deal with something on the level of banking? Should I only make the checkout page https? What is the performance hit on going all out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I personally go with "SSL from go to woe".

If your user never enters a credit card number, sure, no SSL.

But there's an inherent possible security leak from the cookie replay.

1. User visits site and gets assigned a cookie.
2. User browses site and adds data to cart ( using cookie )
3. User proceeds to payment page using cookie.

Right here there is a problem, especially if you have to handle payment negotiation yourself.

You have to transmit information from the non-secure domain to the secure domain, and back again, with no guarantees of protection.

If you do something dumb like share the same cookie with unsecure as you do with secure, you may find some browsers ( rightly ) will just *drop* the cookie completely ( Safari ) for the sake of security, because if somebody sniffs that cookie in the open, they can forge it and use it in the secure mode to, degrading your wonderful SSL security to 0, and if the Card details ever get even temporarily stored in the session, you have a dangerous leak waiting to happen.

If you can't be certain that your software is not prone to these weaknesses, I would suggest SSL from the start, so their initial cookie is transmitted in the secure.

Comment: Small correction - browsers are supposed to keep the cookie between secure and unsecure - which is itself the risk of the application. What you should do if you dont want that - mark your cookie as "secure" - but then you have the issue of how to share the cart between them...

Comment: Couldn't you create a secure connection only cookie (in addition to a non secure login cookie) which is sent over a secure connection when logging in, and require that cookie to checkout?

Answer (score 8):

If the site is for public usage, you should probably put the public parts on HTTP. This makes things easier and more efficient for spiders and casual users. HTTP requests are much faster to initiate than HTTPS and this is very obvious especially on sites with lots of images.

Browsers also sometimes have a different cache policy for HTTPS than HTTP.

But it's alright to put them into HTTPS as soon as they log on, or just before. At the point at which the site becomes personalised and non-anonymous, it can be HTTPS from there onwards.

It's a better idea to use HTTPS for the log on page itself as well as any other forms, as it gives the use the padlock before they enter their info, which makes them feel better.

Comment: I agree - The moment the site is dealing with data which relates to thier identity it should be through ssl.

Comment: Browsing a TLS connection [has no perceptible overhead for client or server](https://istlsfastyet.com) and enabling [HTTPS improves users' privacy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBhZ6S0PFCY) and protects your site from being [modified in transit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07128) by ISPs and core network operators. If HTTP/2 is enabled, TLS can even [improve web page performance](https://www.httpvshttps.com).

Answer (score 5):

I have always done it on the entire website.

Answer (score 4):

I too would use HTTPS all the way. This doesn't have a big performance impact (since browser cache the negociated symmetric key after the first connection) and protects against sniffing.

Sniffing was once on its way out because of fully switched wired networks, where you would have to work extra hard to capture anyone else's traffic (as opposed to networks using hubs), but it's on its way back because of wireless networks, which create a broadcast medium once again an make session hijacking easy, unless the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: Have you heard about ARP spoofing? I understand that there's protection against it, but I wouldn't say that you "have to work extra hard to capture anyone else's traffic."

Comment: Yes, I've heard about ARP spoofing. The "extra hard" part is arguable. I was referring more to the fact that wholesale snooping between ISPs is not very feasible/common (hopefully), but you are entirely right: sniffing the the LAN is quite possible using ARP spoofing.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good rule of thumb is forcing SSL anywhere where sensitive information is going to possibly be transmitted. For example: I'm a member of Wescom Credit Union. There's a section on the front page that allows me to log on to my online bank account. Therefore, the root page forces SSL.

Think of it this way: will sensitive, private information be transmitted? If yes, enable SSL. Otherwise you should be fine.

Comment: Not just transmitted but presented and gathered as well. A non-secure (not using TLS/SSL) form submitting its data to an SSL page is not a good idea.

Comment: Why? If the target URL is an HTTPS url then the data will be encrypted as soon as submit is pressed (well as soon as the browser compiles the POST request). You can certainly gather on HTTP and submit to HTTPS quite safely.

Comment: Because it is not apparent to the user that the form will be submitted to a secure server. Any time you're collecting sensitive data the form should be on a secure server so that the lock icon appears at that point.

Comment: Also, the user has no guarantee that it will be encrypted, or even sent to the correct site. For all he knows, he could be at a bogus site right now.

Comment: To elaborate on AviD, If the login page itself isn't presented from an HTTPS page, then there's not assurances that the MITM didn't inject some javascript to log the username and password typed in, or even just change the target URL completely.

Answer (score 3):

In our organization we have three classifications of applications -

- Low Business Impact - no PII, clear-text storage, clear-text transmission, no access restrictions.
- Medium Business Impact - non-transactional PII e.g. email address.  clear-text storage, SSL from datacenter to client, clear-text in data center, limited storage access.
- High Business Impact - transactional data e.g. SSN, Credit Card etc.  SSL within and outside of datacenter.  Encrypted & Audited Storage.  Audited applications.

We use these criteria to determine partitioning of data, and which aspects of the site require SSL.  Computation of SSL is either done on server or through accelerators such as Netscaler.  As level of PII increases so does the complexity of the audit and threat modelling.

As you can imagine we prefer to do LBI applications.

Answer (score 1):

Generally anytime you're transmitting sensitive or personal data you should be using SSL - e.g. adding an item to a basket probably doesn't need SSL, logging in with your username/password, or entering your CC details should be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I only ever redirect my sites to SSL when it requires the user to enter sensitive information. With a shopping cart as soon as they have to fill out a page with their personal information or credit card details I redirect them to a SSL page.
For the rest of the site its probably not needed - if they are just viewing information/products on your commerce site.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is pretty computationally intensive and should not be used to transmit large amounts of data if possible.  Therfore it would be better to enable it at the checkout stage where the user would be transmitting sensitive information.

Comment: It's not really that computationally intensive at all on today's hardware. It's true the asymmetric cryptography is far more expensive than symmetric, but since all SSL does is use asymmetric keys to encrypt a symmetric session key the whole process is pretty zippy.

Comment: If you have your whole site under SSL then it will be slower than doing it properly - only where necessary

Comment: I'm in total agreement with @Richie_W. SSL does slow things down considerably! Recently, I was going to move my entire site to SSL, but after testing I decided not to. On average using computer browsers, my pages load in 1.5s over HTTP, but take 5s over HTTPS. Using mobile browsers via 3G network the numbers are 17s and 45s, respectively. I found that the biggest slow down factor is the extra round trips needed to negotiate SSL. For instance, 20k image may take 80ms to download, but SSL handshake is 700ms. I also found SSL caching to be inconsistent among browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major downside to a full `https` site and it's not the speed (thats ok).

**It will be very hard to run Youtube, "Like"boxes etc without the unsecure warning.**

We are running a full forces secured website and shop for two years now and this is the biggest drawback. We managed to get Youtube to work now but the "Add this" is still a big challenge. And if they change anything to the protocol then it could be that all our Youtube movies are blank...