# SSL - What should I do for it?

Tags: ssl

I need to enable SSL on my website.

Q1> What should I do to enable this service?

Q2> Should I change my code (i.e. PHP+JavaScript+MySQL )?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should you enable SSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107566/where-should-you-enable-ssl)

Comment: It depends on what are you using as your webserver. Apache, IIS,...? And which operating system are you using? I could give you a description for Linux but it wouldn't fit on Windows due to certificate creation and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Q1> you need to generate a certificate signing request and send it to a trusted certificate authority to be signed, usually for a fee. I use [SSL.com](http://www.ssl.com) regularly because they give me responsive customer support. After they sign the certificate, they will it send back to you or you can download it. Then you install the signed certificate on your server.

If you are running Windows, try http://www.ssltools.com/manager for a tool that generates the csr.

Q2> you can configure it in the server settings, but you can also programmatically implement it in your code. For instance, if you want to open sockets in your code, or if you want SSL on certain pages (although modern servers allow selective SSL implementation in the settings).